# Active Nav Bar Menu Item CSS3 /HTML5

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, html

I currently have this:

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
    var thispage = location.pathname.substring(1);
    //document.write(thispage);
    jQuery('#menu li a[href~="'+ thispage + '"]') // ~= is contains. Tweak as needed.
    .addClass('active');
});
```

CSS:

```
li.active {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="topNav">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="<?=HOST?>/index.php" title="Home">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?=HOST?>/about-us/" title="About Us">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?=HOST?>/technology/" title=" Technology"> TECHNOLOGY</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?=HOST?>/careers/" title="Careers">CAREERS</a>
      <li><a href="<?=HOST?>/blogs/" title="Blogs">BLOG</a>
        <!--<ul>                    
            <li style="background-color:#898486;"><a href="<?=SEEKER_HOST?>/opportunities" title="Current Opportunities">OPPORTUNITIES</a></li>
        </ul>-->
      <li class="last"><a href="<?=SEEKER_HOST?>/contact/index.php" title="Contact Us">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My goal is to each menu item to shade a different color when the page is active.  I have tried numerous ways to fix this but I am unable to get this to work.  in my CSS i even have an element item for :focus, but it only works when the href="#" and not with my current setup.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you might look for `*=` http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector not for `~=` http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/ . The first is the real "contains". The one you used is about contain word and needs word boundaries like spaces. Never used either of them so I'm not sure, myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work with two changes:

```
jQuery('#menu li a[href*="'+ thispage + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

As I suggested in my comment use `*=` as "contains", not `~=` ("contains word"), and I think you wanted to add the `active` class to the `<li/>`, not the `<a/>` tag.